# Why am I getting different submit button placement in Chrome / Firefox when using custom graphics?

Tags: html, css, forms, firefox, google-chrome

I have 2 inputs... a text field and a submit button.  I'm using custom background-images on both via CSS.  The images both have the same height of 18px.  In Chrome the button gets displayed slightly lower than the text-field.  In firefox, it's spot-on.

The CSS I'm using is:

```
.search-field {background: url('search-field.png') no-repeat transparent!important; width: 117px!important; height: 18px!important; border: none!important; margin-right: -7px!important; }

.search-button {background: url('search-button.png') no-repeat transparent!important; width: 16px!important; height: 18px!important; border: none!important; text-indent: -9999!important; text-transform: capitalize!important;}
```

The HTML I'm using is:

```
<div class="search">

    <input class="search-field" type="text" />
    <input class="search-button" type="submit" value="" />

</div>
```

The screenshot below is from Chrome.  I seem to be able to correct it in Chrome after tweaking the CSS for the field, but then it breaks in FF the opposite way.

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML & a screenshot of what it is doing? Have you looked in the inspecter to see whats causing it?

Comment: Updated question w/ HTML / screenshot from Chrome.  I'm not sure what exactly is causing it.  I can fix in in Chrome w/ a position:relative and a top: -4px; but that breaks it in FF the opposite way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this helps.. Check the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/XNNAW/

Comment: Wow!  Thanks!  That fixed it in both browsers.  Can you explain what's happening so I can make sense of it?  I see the added border and the height change for the button (as well as the display: block and float), but I'm still not getting WHY this corrects the problem.  If you find a second and are able to explain it I'd be much obliged!